# Express static is serving CSS and JS but not images

Tags: node.js, express

I have setup `express.static` to serve static assets on my site. I have CSS, JS and images in the same directory. The CSS and JS are served correctly however the images are not.

On `localhost` the images return a `200` response but no image.
On production they return `302` and no image.

My project directory looks like this:

```
|- app.js - Main server file
|
|
|- client - All user facing files
      |
      |- admin - Admin front end
      |      |_ assets - Stores CSS, JS and images 
      |      
      |_ theme - Website front end
             |_ assets - Stores CSS, JS and images
```

The code that I am using to serve the static files in the `app.js` file is:

```
app.use('/admin/assets', express.static(`${__dirname}/client/admin/assets`));
app.use('/assets', express.static(`${__dirname}/client/theme/assets`));
```

I also tried:

```
app.use('/admin/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, `client/admin/assets`)));
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, `client/theme/assets`)));
```

In the front end I am using the following markup to try and render the image:

```
<img src="/assets/avatar.png">
```

I can't figure out why this or any other image won't work but js and css do. For reference the following markup successfully renders the JS:

```
<script defer="defer" src="/assets/index.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if you open it in your browser? do you get 404? `http://yourhost:yourport/assets/avatar.png`

Comment: @GrafiCode I get `304 Not Modified`

Comment: is the image rendered correctly in browser?

Comment: No just a small white border square on a black screen in Chrome.

Comment: are you definitely sure the png image is not corrupted? I mean, if you try it on a different image, a jpeg maybe, is the result always the same?

Comment: Thank you so much, It corrupted. I built a cli that uploads the files to the client directory. It obviously doesn't work with images. So the images were there in the theme repo but when they got pushed to the project folder they broke.

Comment: good luck with that then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this issue was happening was because image files being stored in the directory were becoming corrupted.